# Formatting wordpress text-editor line breaks for fpdf

Tags: php, wordpress, line-breaks, fpdf

I'm currently working on a script that essentially takes a *wordpress* post entry and pastes it into a *pdf* along with a bunch of other info.
When I look at how *wordpress* saves text from its editor to the database, it stores *linebreaks* as simply new lines, without an html tag. *(There must be better way to say this but  I don't know what it is.)*  The library that I'm referencing, FPDF, seems to need an explicit `<br/>` or equivalent to do a line break.

**So my question is:**

1. How do I tell my script to replace these *wordpress linebreaks* with a `<br/>`?
2. Or if you're familiar with FPDF and have a better suggestion, please feel free to share.
3. I'm also looking for the intelligent way to refer to these sans-html-tag "wordpress-created line breaks"

Help with any of these three issues would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can do this with `nl2br`, (http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) like

   echo nl2br($wordpress_text);
2. When you write to FPDF, try

   $pdf->WriteHTML(nl2br($wordpress_text));
3. `nl2br` means New Line to Break Tag `<br/>`, that might be the phrase you're looking for.

Comment: Wow, that was easy!  It worked exactly as you said it would.  Much appreciated.